# Deadlock in asyncpg - how to resolve?

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncpg

I have a simple execution statement that updates if a condition is met. I understand a deadlock is when both process A and B fight for the same resources, and they both rely on another to finish.

However, I just have a simple UPDATE statement, and I can't find the other source of the deadlock - but I was just confused how this line can cause a deadlock statement:

```py
    await self.bot.pg_con.execute("UPDATE gameusers SET raid_pass = raid_pass + 1 WHERE raid_pass < 10")
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 518, in execute
    return await con.execute(query, *args, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 272, in execute
    return await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 316, in query
asyncpg.exceptions.DeadlockDetectedError: deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 24326 waits for ShareLock on transaction 75790925; blocked by process 24240.
Process 24240 waits for ShareLock on transaction 75790924; blocked by process 24326.
```

How can it occur in a simple UPDATE statement?

Thanks for your time.